# Reading return from server.workbooks.refresh using Tableau REST API

Tags: python-3.x, tableau-api

This will probably sound stupid, but I have a python script which is trying to refresh a Tableau Extract using a workbook id on Server.  I have all the code working just fine and I am even getting the extract to work using the server.workbooks.refresh method passing the workbook id in the call.  I am returning the value into a value called "results".  The problem is that I want to pull the job id from the results variable and everything I have tried to reference the id within the "result" variable does not work.  I keep getting an AttributeError 'JobItem' object has no attribute error.

I have tried to reference the object as a string, as a tuple, as a dictionary, and a list.   But I cannot figure out what this object actually is so I can reference the data within it and I cannot find anywhere on the internet that talks about what is returned.

```
results = server.workbooks.refresh(selected_workbook_id)
print(results)
print("\nThe data of workbook {0} is refreshed.".format(results.name))
```

Here is the error after the print statement:

```
<Job#fc62052d-e824-4594-8681-64dbb9a8216c RefreshExtract created_at(2019-11-06 22:18:21+00:00) started_at(None) completed_at(None) progress (None) finish_code(-1)>
https://wnuapesstablu01.dstcorp.net/api/3.4/auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\Python36\Scripts\Tableau REST API Scripts\Refresh_Single_Extract_v2.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\Python36\Scripts\Tableau REST API Scripts\Refresh_Single_Extract_v2.py", line 131, in main
    print("\nThe data of workbook {0} is refreshed.".format(results.name))
AttributeError: 'JobItem' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: did you retrieve the notebook - `workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id("id")`

Comment: @R4444 -- yes, I am actually pulling all the workbooks notebooks on the server using:

all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()

then having the user select which workbook they want to refresh and using the workbook.id from the selected workbook notebook.

Answer (score 0):

To close this issue out.  I realized that I needed to use the right API reference for the JobItem Class.  See https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#jobs

Valid references are things like "id", "type", "created_at", "started_at".  So the for those who didn't understand this like me, the reference is:

```
workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id(selected_workbook_id)

results = server.workbooks.refresh(workbook.id)
print(results)

jobid = results.id
```

This will return the job id that the refresh task started on.  You can then write a routine to poll the server looking to see when the extract job is finished.

Hope this helps someone... It was driving me crazy.